# .Net 5 console app, how to target ARM platform?

Tags: .net, windows-10-iot-core

I am tring to build .net 5 console app for Windows 10 Iot platform. Howewer I am not able to add ARM as platform to debug and deploy app.
[image]

Am I missing smt?

If I create windows UWP app, it is already there:
[image]

Comment: Solution Platform only matters to the kind of project that cares about the user's platform.  Notably C++ projects, you use a very different compiler and linker since C++ compilers generate machine code.  UWP is a bit of special case, the Store server needs to know what platforms you are willing to support and it determines what .NET Native does.  For C# projects, the machine code is generated on the user's machine, by the just-in-time compiler.  Which is why AnyCPU is the default and sensible choice.

Comment: But then I am not able to remotly debug on my raspberry

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the debug setting for ARM platform manually. But it seems that there is no document about how to install .net 5.0 on Windows IoT Core.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, but on new solution platform I don`t have ARM

Comment: @SergiyKostenko, you need to create the solution platform for ARM manually, as mentioned in above(click "New" to add the platform).

Comment: I know, but I am not able to add new ARM platform. If I modify sln file manualy it gives error.